# Value of a variable is not updating

Tags: c#, variables

I am currently working on a project that sweeps a mailbox for attachments and when one is found it is placed in the user's directory.  My problem is that when I check if the file exist in the path, I alter the attachment's name and add a counter and time stamp, that way it is not over written.  However, when it goes into the condition and changes the file name it never updates the path variable to include the right value of the Clean name variable.

```
string timeProcessed = DateTime.Now.ToString();
byte[] bytefiles = attachment.ContentBytes;
string cleanName = MakeCleanName(userEmail.Subject, attachment.Name);       
string path = employeeStarPath + "\\" + cleanName;
// updated this in order to prevent images with the same name from overwritting eachother.
if (File.Exists(path))
{                                  
    cleanName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(attachment.Name).ToString()+"(" + counter + ")" + "-(Recieved - " + timeProcessed.Replace(":",".").Replace("/",".") + " )"+ Path.GetExtension(attachment.Name); << this value is not updated in the path variable.

}
```

Now I am aware I can update the path var by calling `path = employeeStarPath + "\\" + cleanName;` again but I feel that this makes my code a bit confusing.

Comment: Yea, had to walk away from the monitor, I am going to restructure my code a bit, just keeping in mind another person who may come in after me

Comment: What is the difference between what happens in the MakeCleanName method and what you are doing within the `if (File.Exists(path))` block? I think you would really only want to do one of those statements, depending on what is actually going on.

Comment: Yea exactly what I was thinking, I am going to to do my file check in my Makeclean method that way it looks a by better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might not understood your question but can you just call the line "string path = employeeStarPath + "\" + cleanName;" at the end instead before the if?

```
string timeProcessed = DateTime.Now.ToString();
byte[] bytefiles = attachment.ContentBytes;
string cleanName = MakeCleanName(userEmail.Subject, attachment.Name);       

// updated this in order to prevent images with the same name from overwritting eachother.
if (File.Exists(path))
{                                  
    cleanName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(attachment.Name).ToString()+"(" + counter + ")" + "-(Recieved - " + timeProcessed.Replace(":",".").Replace("/",".") + " )"+ Path.GetExtension(attachment.Name); << this value is not updated in the path variable.

}

string path = employeeStarPath + "\\" + cleanName;
```